# How can I retrieve the file that the user chose in tkinter python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I wrote this function that I added in the command of the button knowing that I want to retrieve a `wav` audio file and "inputpath" is an entry where I want to insert the path of the file chosen by the user with a button "Open file"

```
def select_file():

    filetypes = (
        ('wav files', '*.wav'),
        ('All files', '*.*')
    )

    filename = fd.askopenfilename(
        title='Open a file',
        initialdir='/',
        filetypes=filetypes)
    showinfo( 
        title='File selected'   
        
    )
    inputpath.insert=(filename)
```

Comment: Why do you have an `=` at `inputpath.insert=(filename)`, it should be `inputpath.insert('end',filename)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to insert the path into the `entry` widget, you'll have to set an index for the `inputpath.insert()` function.

**For example:**

```
def select_file():

    filetypes = (
        ('wav files', '*.wav'),
        ('All files', '*.*')
    )

    filename = fd.askopenfilename(
        title='Open a file',
        initialdir='/',
        filetypes=filetypes)
   
    inputpath.insert=(END, filename)

select_file()
```

Here I changed the `inputpath.insert(filename)` to `inputpath.insert(END, filename)`

I hope this solves your problem!

Comment: Potential for `NameError`.

Comment: Depends on how you imported ```tkinter```. For example when ```import tkinter as tk``` you'll get ```inputpath.insert(tk.END, filename)```

Comment: So always safe to say `'end'`.